# html table tag not displaying all the cell elements in same column of various rows alligned

Tags: html

### html table tag not working as required

I have tried 100% width also but it is not helping the cells are sized according to their content and so are not same in a same column. thanx a lot for your help in advance!

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Comment: jsfiddle would be a great way to post it.

Comment: out.println("<form action=update.jsp>"+"<table border=2"+"<tr><td>"+"qid:</td><td>"+rs.getString("qid")+"</tr></td>"+"<tr><td>"+"Question:</td><td>"+"<input type=text name= q1 value="+rs.getString("question")+" maxlength=1000></td></tr>"+"<tr><td>"+"ANS1:</td><td>"+"<input type=text name= q2 value="+rs.getString("ans1")+"></td></tr>"+"<tr><td>"+"ANS2:</td><td>"+"<input type=text name= q3 value="+rs.getString("ans2")+"></td></tr>"+"<tr><td>"+"ANS3:</td><td>"+"<input type=text name= q4 value="+rs.getString("ans3")+"></td></tr><tr><td><input type=submit value=change></td></tr></table>");

Comment: it is used in a jsp page. So i have used this format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use DIVs?

**That's HTML:**

```
<div class="column1">111111111111111</div><div class="column2"><img src="http://i1129.photobucket.com/albums/m517/Fireballx576/0e1252115_overflow_zpsd61dbce3.jpg" /></div><div class="column3">333333333333333</div>
```

**That's CSS:**

```
.column1,
.column2,
.column3 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-x: hidden; /* prevents content from expanding the cells */
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

Here's JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trb6z1s4/1/

Comment: i used your previous method using css. it was helful and it worked thanx a lot. Also used jsfiddle for the first time its very useful